# What's bitters to use with bourbon, blood orange syrup, lemon juice and pinot noir?

Tags: recommendations, whiskey, ingredients, cocktails

The best cocktail I've ever had is at Santo Mezcal in Santa Barbara, California called the [Riveria Hermosa](https://www.santomezcalsb.com/menu).

The ingredients shown in the menu just say "bitters". I'm wondering what bitters would go best with the other ingredients: bourbon, blood orange syrup, lemon juice, and pinot noir. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 5):

**What's bitters to use with *bourbon, blood orange syrup, lemon juice and pinot noir*?**

Bitters have been around for along time, but have come back into favor as part of the current craft cocktail trend. The two most traditional kinds are Peychaud’s and Angostura, both crucial players in whiskey cocktails such as the [Manhattan](https://ezrabrooks.com/cocktails/manhattan/) and the [old-fashioned](https://ezrabrooks.com/cocktails/old-fashioned/). But these days, the sky’s the limit.

Taking into consulting the ingredients of the cocktail you are interested in, I would recommend using **Angostura bitters** based on this [particular recipe](https://food52.com/recipes/26200-old-fashioned-cocktail-w-blood-orange-syrup).

The only additional ingredient would be the *Pinot noir* wine.

I am confident that the Angostura bitters will work it’s magic quite well.

And by the way.

Bone Appetite!

Answer (score 1):

Angostura bitters is always a safe bet.

Regan's Orange bitters work well with bourbon, and would complement the blood orange syrup.

The unusual / wild card ingredient is the Pinot Noir. Cherry bitters would be interesting, and would also complement the bourbon.

But I'm going to say that Rhubarb bitters is the way to go. They would contrast the wine, the syrup, and the lemon, hence bringing the most complexity to the drink.